# Root not available?

Tags: root-access

## Root not avaliable?

So far all of Rooting APK's Either don't download (Just disappears)
Or say Root failed or not available.

- ### So far These are what ive used.
- KingRoot
- KingoRoot
- OneClickRoot
  -

If possible can someone tell me Rooting programs that I haven't used that might work.

Comment: add info about your device and os version to let our users provide specific solutions. Meanwhile you can check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device/1185#1185)

Comment: Mtk droid tools is for mediatk devices. There is framaroot is an apk also but very specific in devices it can root.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise heavily against one click solutions, as they are frequently malware ridden - I wouldn't want to give malware root access.

Unlock the bootloader, flash TWRP and then flash magisk for safe root.